# javascript,php - How to position child window in center?

Tags: javascript

what is the correct value of left and top to position the child window in the center?
I tried left=500 and top=500 but the window is now on the bottom of the page.
here is the code:

```
<a href="items.php?desc='.urlencode($row[7]).'"onClick="MM_openBrWindow(\'items.php? desc='.urlencode($row[7]).'\',\'google\',\'width=650,height=500,left=500,top=5\'); return false;">
<img src="Folder-Blank-icon.png"></a>
```

Comment: Why are you sending left/top 500? Your snippet is referencing other methods and elements which seem relevant, but there is no code regarding them, it would be useful to see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should get user's display resolution using JS
2. Set top and left params then

   document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);

Might not work in older browsers, but will in most recent ones.

More info here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Comment: how? I am new to javascript.

Comment: @user2335183 https://www.google.com/search?q=get+user's+display+resolution+using+JS

Comment: @paulius after getting the resolution, how can i set the parameters?

Comment: You should try to count some ratio which could be used when setting left and top. i.e: var responsive_left = screen.width * 0.3; var responsive_top = screen. height * 0.1;